# laravel - How can I get the user information of each comment

Tags: php, laravel, model

I have these Models:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'post_id';
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'post_id', 'post_id');
    }
}

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'comment_id';

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'post_id');
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'user_id', 'commenter_id');
    }
}

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function post($id = null)
    {
        $post = Post::where('post_id', $id)->first();
        $comments = $post->comments;
    }
}
```

What I want is to get the user of each comment something like `$post->comments->user` in order to get the user information easy like below:

```
@foreach($post->comments as $comment)
    {{ $comment->user->first_name.' '.$comment->user->last_name }}
@endforeach
```

How can I do this? I guess I need something named `hasManyThrough` but it's too complex and I got confused :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can get the user object with comment object, using

```
$post = Post::with('comments.user')->where('post_id', $id)->first();
```

and define mapping for user in comments models

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'comment_id';

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'post_id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: When I want to get the result with `$comments = $post->comments->user;` it throws error `Property [user] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: @kodfire you need to loop through your comments and then on  each comment object you can access user object, you cannot access user object on collection of comments

Comment: Thank you very much @MKhalidJunaid By the way what if I don't include that `with('comments.user')` in my query?

Comment: `with()` is basically for eager loading in your case if you are looping your data then you don't need this

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid he doesn't need it but if he loops he will execute a query for each comment, so I'd say that he does need it for perfomance improvements

Comment: @GaimZz I totally agree with you, In his case eager loading would be a better approach

Answer (score 0):

Just create function in your Comment model which must return relation like this

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

And then call this function on your comment object